# Files & directories routine

Tags: java, file, directory

I've got some problems trying to print available directories on the screen.

Here's some code with two possible ways to print it:

```
File f = new File(System.getProperty("user.home"));

System.out.println(java.util.Arrays.toString(f.list())); //the FIRST way

for (String fileName : f.list()) {  //the SECOND
    System.out.println(fileName);   // way
}
```

Looks like it's a pretty good way to print directories but it prints more directories than really exist.

Thus I have to 2 questions: How to print it correctly? How to print it correctly but from another directory, not from "user.home"?

UPD!!! Ok guys, I've just found out that the problem is that it shows even hidden directories. 
So now please help me to print not hidden directories only.

Comment: `but it prints more directories than really exist` sure? `How to print it correctly but from another directory` ... provide a different directory in `new File("/path/blub")`.

Comment: Do you only want directories? Because you're printing all the files as well as the directories.

Comment: I'm almost sure, mb there some invisible directories? But my default Windows 8.1 folder search can't find anything

Comment: `File.list` doesn't return only directories, it returns all paths in a directory, whether these point to plain files, directories or other things. You need to be more specific about your problem. What exactly does it print? What is the output of `dir` or `ls` (depending on your OS) on the same directory. Aren't you just using your two methods in succession, hence printing everything twice?

Comment: There are no files in my Home directory

Comment: *What does it print?*

Comment: The directories that you said does not exist, aren't they hidden directories ?

Comment: It prints:
.designer
.eclipse
.IdeaIC13
.jmc
.nbi
.netbeans-derby
.VirtualBox
AppData
Application Data
Cloud@Mail.Ru
Contacts
Cookies
Desktop
Documents
Downloads
Favorites
Google Диск
IdeaProjects
IntelGraphicsProfiles
Links
Local Settings
Music
NetHood
NTUSER.DAT
ntuser.dat.LOG1
ntuser.dat.LOG2
NTUSER.DAT{014c31ae-ae7f-11e3-80bb-90b11c269051}.TM.blf
NTUSER.DAT{014c31ae-ae7f-11e3-80bb-90b11c269051}.TMContainer00000000000000000001.regtrans-ms
NTUSER.DAT{014c31ae-ae7f-11e3-80bb-90b11c269051}.TMContainer00000000000000000002.regtrans-ms

Comment: And

ntuser.ini
OneDrive
Pictures
PrintHood
Recent
Saved Games
Searches
SendTo
Videos
VirtualBox VMs
главное меню
Мои документы
Шаблоны

Comment: Stuff like that etc doesn't exist!!!

NetHood
NTUSER.DAT
ntuser.dat.LOG1
ntuser.dat.LOG2
NTUSER.DAT{014c31ae-ae7f-11e3-80bb-90b11c269051}.TM.blf
NTUSER.DAT{014c31ae-ae7f-11e3-80bb-90b11c269051}.TMContainer00000000000000000001.regtrans-ms
NTUSER.DAT{014c31ae-ae7f-11e3-80bb-90b11c269051}.TMContainer00000000000000000002.regtrans-ms
ntuser.ini

Comment: Please post additional data by editing your question, and not in comments.

Comment: Ok. Try `System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.home"));` in Java. Then take your Windows explorer to *that* directory and check whether you see the same files that were shown to you in Java.

Comment: No =( It's not the same

Comment: And don't forget to show also hidden and system files in the explorer to see everything.

Comment: Those files all look like normal hidden files in Windows user directories to me.

Comment: @BoristheSpider, Ok, but how to print only not hidden directories?

Comment: I would start by reading [the Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) before writing random code. For example, what do you reckon `File.isHidden` does?

Comment: @BoristheSpider I guess it returns false if file is not hidden else it returns true

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use .isHidden() to determine wheter a file or directory is hidden.

Just modify Jamie's solution slightly for your needs:

```
for (File f : f.listFiles())
{
  if (!f.isHidden())
  {
    System.out.println(f.getName());
  }
}
```

Comment: That's the answer I really need =) Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

To only list directories, you will need to use f.listFiles(), and check each one in the result for isDirectory().

```
for (File sub : f.listFiles())
{
  if (sub.isDirectory())
  {
    System.out.println(sub.getName());
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I need to print directories and files. Actually I'm trying to make ls (Unix) or DIR (Windows).

Comment: By the way. The output by DIR and by your way aren't the same. Your method prints more directories. Looks like it prints hidden dirs. But how to print not hidden ONLY?
Thank You!